# How to get objects out of a distinct() in Django?

Tags: django

I wonder if this query can be modified to return `User` objects instead of just `merchant_id` (`User`).

```
(User.objects.get(id=merchant['merchant_id']) for merchant in self.user.visits.values('merchant_id').distinct())
```

Comment: `User.objects.get()` means it returns `User` objects.  What problem are you having?

Comment: Not a problem, this is working, but I want it to directly return a User object no an id (in the generator expression not in the output expression).

Comment: Ideally what I can do is: `self.user.visits.order_by('merchant').distinct())` just to put `merchant` in the `select`.

Comment: But I do not want to sort by merchant, I just want to put merchant_id in the select statement and return User objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating 1 DB query for each User (which is a Merchant?) lookup. Need to brush up on my django ORM but I would do something like:

```
User.objects.filter(id__in=[ merchant['merchant_id'] for merchant in self.user.visits.values('merchant_id').distinct() ])
```

Answer (score 1):

How does this sound?

```
merchants_visited = self.user.visits.merchants.all().distinct()
return User.objects.filter(visits__merchants__in=merchants_visited, profile=self)
```

Comment: This looks slower than my query, like I said in my previous comment, I just need to put merchant in the select statement and that `distinct()` returns `User` objects.